# Recover of important files on hard drive impossible

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I was updating my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 14.10 because I think it should correct a bug that was really annoying me. But instead, the update didn't went well, and now I can't boot my pc anymore. 
So I took back my old 14.04 key and I'm now in the mode "testing Ubuntu" in order to recover the files of the hard drive into a micro sd card (in order to make a clean installation (wipe the drive)) but I can't as it says

> the folder can't be handled because you don't have the permissions to read it

How can I recover this files ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksudo nautilus
```

Now copy the files.

Comment: @JiexDrop Just do `sudo -H nautilus`. It can be done without gksu.

Comment: @JiexDrop, Glad to hear. Delete unnecessary comments, and tell us how you did it, so that it may help others.